# I send an image to server through REST api using multipart formdata but it gets corrupted

Tags: c#, uwp, multipartform-data

From the given below code I convert image into bytearray then send it to server through multipartform data using REST API post method. It sends the bytearray on server but when I fetch the same Image from server I got the message that image format is corrupted. I cannot understand the error.

```
public static async Task < HomeWorkResponse > CreateHomeWork(HomeWorkRequest homeWork, UserData user) {
    try {
        MultipartFormDataContent Mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent("Upload----" + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        List < KeyValuePair < string,
        string >> Post_parameters = null;
        string token = "";
        var result = await ServerMethods.GetTokenForTLE();
        if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.response.token)) {
            token = result.response.token;
        }

        //Convert Image into bytearray

        for (int i = 0; i < homeWork.attachmentspath.Count; i++) {
            Mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            StorageFile sfs = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(homeWork.attachmentspath[i]);
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            byte[] imageByteArray = null;
            using(var stream = await sfs.OpenReadAsync()) {
                imageByteArray = new byte[stream.Size];
                using(var reader = new DataReader(stream)) {
                    await reader.LoadAsync((uint) stream.Size);
                    reader.ReadBytes(imageByteArray);
                }
            }

            //Add that bytearray into http content

            HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.Length);
            Mfdc.Add(content);
            content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(sfs.ContentType);
            content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("filename");
            content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = sfs.DisplayName;
            Mfdc.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(sfs.ContentType);
            form.Add(Mfdc, i.ToString(), homeWork.attachments[i]);
        }

        //Add different types of data in form data

        form.Add(new StringContent(user.user_id), "user_id");
        form.Add(new StringContent(user.user_session_id), "session_id");
        form.Add(new StringContent(homeWork.subject_id), "subject_id");
        form.Add(new StringContent(homeWork.section_id), "section_id");
        form.Add(new StringContent(homeWork.class_id), "class_id");
        form.Add(new StringContent(user.school_id), "school_id");
        form.Add(new StringContent(homeWork.assignment_title), "title");
        form.Add(new StringContent(homeWork.content), "content");
        form.Add(new StringContent("class-section"), "channel");
        form.Add(new StringContent("mobile"), "origin");
        form.Add(new StringContent("homework"), "type");
        form.Add(new StringContent(""), "homework_id");
        form.Add(new StringContent(homeWork.target_date), "target_date");
        form.Add(new StringContent(homeWork.section_id), "classsec_ids");
        form.Add(new StringContent(""), "group_ids");
        form.Add(new StringContent(""), "file_list");
        form.Add(new StringContent("class"), "assign_to");
        form.Add(new StringContent(token), "token");

        //send the data on server through REST API using post method

        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(string.Format(UrlHelpers.TLE_TEACHER_CREATE_HOMEWORK_URL), form);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        httpClient.Dispose();

        string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var DeserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < HomeWorkResponse > (sd);
        return (HomeWorkResponse) Convert.ChangeType(DeserializeObject, typeof(HomeWorkResponse));

    }
    catch(Exception e) {

}
}
```

From this code I convert my image into bytearray from my system

```
for (int i = 0; i < homeWork.attachmentspath.Count; i++) {
    Mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    StorageFile sfs = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(homeWork.attachmentspath[i]);
    FileStream fileStream = null;
    byte[] imageByteArray = null;
    using(var stream = await sfs.OpenReadAsync()) {
        imageByteArray = new byte[stream.Size];
        using(var reader = new DataReader(stream)) {
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint) stream.Size);
            reader.ReadBytes(imageByteArray);
        }
    }
```

And this is the code in java which was used by android team and their images uploaded sucessfully

```
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
stringArrayList = sourceFileUr;
// defaultHttpClient
InputStream inputStream;
File sourceFile;
byte[] data;
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
InputStreamBody inputStreamBody;
if (stringArrayList != null && stringArrayList.size() > 0) {
    String allFile = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArrayList.size(); i++) {
        String fileName = stringArrayList.get(i).substring(stringArrayList.get(i).lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        String Fullpath = stringArrayList.get(i);
        sourceFile = new File(Fullpath);
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        data = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        inputStreamBody = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), fileName);
        entity.addPart("" + i, inputStreamBody);
        //  entity.addPart("file_name", new StringBody(fileName));
        jsonObject.put("" + i, Fullpath);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to upload an image to server, you don't need to convert image into bytearray, you can just upload the image by providing HTTP content that uses a stream using the [HttpStreamContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpstreamcontent) Class in the [Windows.Web.Http](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http) Namespace. Here is the example code, you can have a try in your app.

```
    //using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient 
    public async Task<bool> ShareStatusWithPicture(string text, StorageFile file)
    {
        Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
        var fileContent = new HttpStreamContent(await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
        fileContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        var content = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();
        Uri uri = new Uri("URI of your server");
        content.Add(fileContent, "pic", file.Name);
        content.Add(new HttpStringContent(tokens.AccessToken), "access_token");
        content.Add(new HttpStringContent("homework"), "status");
        //TO DO 
        //Add other HttpStringContent
        Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        client.Dispose();
        return msg.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
```

---Update---

You can try the following code to covert your image into bytearray:

```
for (int i = 0; i < homeWork.attachmentspath.Count; i++)
{
    Mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    StorageFile sfs = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(homeWork.attachmentspath[i]);
    FileStream fileStream = null;
    byte[] imageByteArray = null;
    using (var stream = await sfs.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        imageByteArray = new byte[stream.Size];
        using (var reader = new DataReader(stream))
        {
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
            // Keep reading until we consume the complete stream.
            while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
            {
                uint bytesToRead = reader.ReadUInt32();
                reader.ReadBytes(imageByteArray);
            }
        }
    }
```

If these code still don't work, you can use the [Stream.CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netframework-4.7.2) Method, then convert the copied stream to array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < homeWork.attachmentspath.Count; i++)
{
    Mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    StorageFile sfs = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(homeWork.attachmentspath[i]);
    FileStream fileStream = null;
    byte[] imageByteArray = null;
    using (var stream = await sfs.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        //imageByteArray = new byte[stream.Size];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.AsStream().CopyTo(ms);
            imageByteArray= ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: But my compulsion is only send in bytearray , so please can u tell me how i send in bytearray.

Comment: I have added the **Update** part in my answer, you can check it. If they both don't work, please provide a simple sample to help me look into your issue.

Comment: from first method it gives exception that The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range and from second method result is same of corrupted image

Comment: Our API team apply the loopback at their end in node.js and that work properly on other platforms i.e. android , ios and web application so they not change their logic.

Comment: @ Breeze Liu - MSFT thanks your answer helps me to think about streamcontent

Answer (score 2):

By using the given below code I have solved my problem

```
for (int i = 0; i < Postdata.Attachment_Path.Count; i++)
                {
                    Mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    StorageFile sfs = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Postdata.Attachment_Path[i]);
                     await Task.Run(async () => {
                         FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(sfs.Path);
                         var streamContent = new StreamContent(fs);
                         var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
                         imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
                         form.Add(imageContent, i.ToString(), Postdata.Attached_filename[i]);
                     });
                }
```

Comment: Please do not use File.OpenRead on a StorageFile Path. `await sfs.OpenStreamForReadAsync()` will do the job, and safer too, and without thread blocking. If you're gong to use File.OpenRead you didn't even need to get the StorageFile in the first place - it literally has no purpose to you. Also try never to call `.Result` on a Task (`streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result`) - use `await streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` instead.

Comment: @Johnny Westlake thanks for your suggestion I made the changes according to you and its working fine